# add values to array of keys with JQ

Tags: json, object, key, jq

I have a simple JSON array:

```
[
"smoke-tests",
"other-tests"
]
```

I'd like to convert to a simple JSON:

```
{"smoke-tests": true,
 "other-tests": true
}
```

I've tried several jq examples, but none seem to do what I want.

`jq '.[] | walk(.key = true)'` produces a compile error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like the efficiency of `reduce` but don't want to use `reduce` explicitly:

```
. as $in | {} | .[$in[]] = true
```

Comment: Thanks, @peak; Elegant and simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ s='["smoke-tests", "other-tests"]'
$ jq '[.[] | {(.): true}] | add' <<<"$s"
{
  "smoke-tests": true,
  "other-tests": true
}
```

Breaking down how that works: `.[] | {(.): true}` converts each item into a dictionary mapping the value (as a key) to `true`. Surrounding that in `[ ]` means we generate a list of such objects; sending that to `add` combines them into a single object.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using add.  It's close to [Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy)'s solution but uses the behavior of [Object construction](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#ObjectConstruction:%7B%7D) to implicitly return multiple objects when used with an expression which returns multiple results.

```
 [{(.[]):true}]|add
```

Answer (score 0):

With `reduce()` function:

```
jq 'reduce .[] as $k ({}; .[$k]=true)' file
```

The output:

```
{
  "smoke-tests": true,
  "other-tests": true
}
```